# "Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'commit')" in nuxt

Tags: javascript, vue.js, nuxt.js, vuex

i dont know why am i getting this error

Here is my code in component:

```
export default{

 methods: {
    updateHighPrice($event) {
      this.$store.commit('setHighPrice', $event.target.value)
    },
}
```

and her is my code in store.js

```
const store = createStore({
  state () {
    return {
        cart:[],
        cartItems:0,
        checkoutStatus: null,
        highprice: 1500,
        sale: false
    }
  },
   mutations:{
    setHighPrice(state, event) {
        state.highprice = event
      },
}
})
```

I tried to change 'commit' to 'dispatch' but it still not working

Comment: Mind sharing more about it? Like how you installed it in your app?

Comment: yarn add vuex@next --save

Comment: Oh wait, you're using Nuxt. So you don't need to install it with Nuxt. Which version of Nuxt are you using?

Comment: "nuxt": "^2.15.3"